# onsubmit event is not executed before submission of form when added in js

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this big JS object in a .js file:

```
//Create object for numbering name attributes of lift and cardio rows
var nameNumberManager = {

    reNameNumberAll: function(){
        alert(1);
        var liftRows = this.getLiftRows();
        alert(2);
        this.reNameNumberLiftRows(liftRows);
        alert(3);
        var cardioRows = this.getCardioRows();
        alert(4);
        this.reNameNumberCardioRows(cardioRows);
        alert(5);
        // get all cardio rows
    },
    getLiftRows: function(){
        var liftRows = document.getElementById('liftrows');
        return liftRows;
    },
    getCardioRows: function(){
        var cardioRows = document.getElementById('cardiorows');
        return cardioRows;
    },
    reNameNumberLiftRows: function(liftRows){
        for(var i=0; i<liftRows.length; i++){
            var liftField = liftRows.getElementsByClassName('input').getElementsByClassName('lift')[0];
            var setField = liftRows.getElementsByClassName('setfield');
            var repFields = liftRows.getElementsByClassName('repfield');
            var weightFields = liftRows.getElementsByClassName('weightfield');

            liftField.name = 'lift_string'+i;
            setField.name = 'sets'+i;
            for(var j=0; i<repFields.length; j++){
                repFields[i].name = 'reps'+i;
            }
            for(var j=0; i<weightFields.length; j++){
                weightFields[i].name = 'weight'+i;
            }

        }
    },
    reNameNumberCardioRows: function(cardioRows){
        for(var i=0; i<cardioRows.length; i++){
            var activityField = cardioRows.getElementsByClassName('dropdowntext');
            var minField = cardioRows.getElementsByClassName('minfield');
            var distField = cardioRows.getElementsByClassName('distfield');

            activityField.name = 'cardio_string'+i;
            minField.name = 'minutes'+i;
            distField.name = 'distance'+i;
        }
    },
}
```

I would like one of its methods to be executed right before my form is submitted.

If I add the event like this:

```
//Adding numbering of name attribute for fields onsubmit on form
var workoutform = document.getElementById('workoutform');
workoutform.onsubmit = nameNumberManager.reNameNumberAll;
```

I only get the first of the alert statements (`alert(5);`) executed. This must mean my whole function is not executed.

But if I add the event like this, in the HTML:

```
<form id="workoutform" onsubmit="return nameNumberManager.reNameNumberAll()" action="{% url 'workoutcal:add_workout' date.year date.month date.day %}" method="post">
```

All of the alert statements are executed. Why this difference? How can I make it so that my whole function is executed before submission when adding the event handler in my .js file?

jquery answers not preferred.

Comment: Whatever happens in the `onsubmit` event does not in any way stop the propagation of the submission of the form, so the browser will load whatever page is in the `action` attribute. So you need to "cancel" the form submission by for example using a `return false;` in your onsubmit.

Comment: `workoutform.submit()` should do :)